# Count and filter data based on paired data/every two rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

Trying to set up for a McNemar test, but I cannot code very well (using R)

My data is paired, and it is 1000 pairs long, so I have a column specifying the pair number like

```
 c(0 , 0 , 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
```

A column specifying which member of the pair is in the control group or treatment (each pair has one of each player, but in a random order) like:

```
c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

And there is a column called response, in which neither, one, or both of the members of the pair could receive a response like:

```
c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

I am trying to create a matrix counting up the results, like:

```
a <- count of pairs in which both members received a response
b <- count of pairs in which the control only received a response
c <- treatment only response
d <- Neither response
matrix(c(a, b, c, d), 2, 2)
```

What lines of code could I run to filter my data to get a, b, c, and d?
I have been trying to use the tidyverse package, so it could be base R or tidyverse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach with `tidyverse`/`dplyr` works:

**1.Loading your data**:

```
library(tidyverse)

pair <- c(0 , 0 , 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
treat <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
response <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
data <- data.frame(pair, treat, response)
```

**2. Computing the counts you want:**

```
d <- data %>% group_by(pair) %>%
    mutate(total_response = sum(response)) %>%
    ungroup() %>% mutate(a = case_when(
        total_response==2 ~ 1,
        TRUE ~ 0),
        b = case_when(
            total_response==1 & treat==0 & response == 1 ~ 1,
        TRUE ~ 0),
        c = case_when(
            total_response==1 & treat==1 & response == 1  ~ 1,
        TRUE ~ 0), 
        d = case_when(
            total_response == 0 ~ 1,
        TRUE ~ 0)) %>% group_by(pair) %>%
    summarise(a = max(a),
              b = max(b),
              c = max(c),
              d = max(d)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    summarise(a = sum(a),
              b = sum(b),
              c = sum(c),
              d = sum(d))
```

**3. Your matrix:**

```
matrix(c(d$a, d$b, d$c, d$d), 2, 2)
```

**4. Explaining the computations:**

1. First, you sum responses grouped by pairs;
2. Then, you ungroup, and when there are two responses by pair, a=1; when one response and control responded, b=1; when one response and treated responded, c=1; when no response, d=1;
3. Then, you group by pairs again and get the max of each letter value, so you get only one letter value by pair;
4. Finally, you ungroup and sum the ones for each variable (equivalent of counting the ones for each of them);

Comment: The matrix has three more counts than the total pairs (5). 'b' should have zero counts.

Comment: @LC-datascientist , thanks for pointing out. I edited and corrected the problem. A condition was missing on case_when clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your dataframe looks like this

```
> d
   group treatment response
1      0         0        0
2      0         1        1
3      1         1        1
4      1         0        1
5      2         1        1
6      2         0        0
7      3         0        0
8      3         1        0
9      4         0        0
10     4         1        1
```

Then you can try something like this

```
d <- within(d, {
  response <- factor(response, levels = c(1, 0), labels = c("positive", "negative"))
  treatment <- as.logical(treatment)
})

with(d, table(response[!treatment], response[treatment], dnn = c("control", "treatment")))
```

Output

```
          treatment
control    positive negative
  positive        1        0
  negative        3        1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using the `dplyr` R package:

```r
library(dplyr)

# your data
df <- data.frame(
    pair = c(0 , 0 , 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), 
    treatment = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
    response = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))

# data management
df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(pair) %>% 
    arrange(treatment) %>% 
    summarise_all(funs(toString(na.omit(.))))
df2
## A tibble: 5 x 3
#   pair treatment response
#  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>   
#1     0 0, 1      0, 1    
#2     1 0, 1      1, 1    
#3     2 0, 1      0, 1    
#4     3 0, 1      0, 0    
#5     4 0, 1      0, 1 

# contingency table
df2 %>% summarise(
    a = sum(response == '1, 1'), # count of pairs in which both members received a response
    b = sum(response == '1, 0'), # count of pairs in which the control only received a response
    c = sum(response == '0, 1'), # count of pairs in which the treatment only received a response
    d = sum(response == '0, 0')  # count of pairs in which neither members received a response
) %>% matrix(2,2)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] 1    3   
#[2,] 0    1
```

**Explanation: Data Management**

The goal here is to use `summarise_all(funs(toString(na.omit(.))))` to collapse response values from paired rows. This will allow you to determine how many paired c(1, 1), c(1, 0), c(0, 1), and c(0, 0) responses are in the data.

`group_by(pair)` makes all further operations to be done within `pair` groups.
`arrange(treatment)` reorders rows based on `treatment` column (within each `pair` group) so that the order of control response and treatment response are always in the same order for each pair--i.e, the paired responses will always be control first, treatment second.
`summarise_all(funs(toString(na.omit(.))))` concatenates all non-NA elements (within each `pair` group) onto a row.

Specifically because of `group_by(pair)` and `summarise_all(...)`, `df2` has one row for each `pair` identifier.

**Explanation: Contingency Table**

Within `summarise(...)`, the count of each TRUE response condition is assigned to their respective vector. The contingency table (matrix) is created from the counts, the same way `matrix(c(a, b, c, d), 2, 2)` in question is organized.